# wordpress :: WP_QUERY is n't sorting the posts by title

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

i'm using WP_QUERY to get posts. the problem is that i want to sort the posts by title, but something is going wrong. i could get the posts but not sorted.

i traced WP_QUERY class and i found that this is the select query that it produced

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts . * 
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id ) 
WHERE 1 =1
AND (
wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
IN ( 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 )
)
AND wp_posts.post_type =  'ecommerce'
AND (
wp_posts.post_status =  'publish'
OR wp_posts.post_status =  'private'
)
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY  `wp_posts`.`post_title` ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

it's obvious that it's ordering by post title correctly, but i'm not sure what is the problem

any help ?

Thanks

Comment: What is wrong with the results? Can you post the first few rows (the `title` field)?

Comment: Perhaps some titles have spaces in the left characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps some titles have spaces in the left characters. Can you try with:

```
ORDER BY  LTRIM(wp_posts.post_title) ASC
```